# run a executable jar in windows server

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, windows-server-2012

I am using windows server to run my application. Application is built on spring boot & angular 2. I want to run the executable jar in the windows server.

I have the following queries.

1. Which is the best practice to run the jar rather than running java -jar abc.jar in cmd.
2. Best practice to log the application logs in the above configuration.

Comment: Are you not using a Java Web server? Tomcat, for example?

Comment: I am using embedded tomcat which comes with spring boot

Comment: Okay, then you should be able to start tomcat as a service and run a WAR / JAR file from there

Comment: Whats the difference between running a jar as service and running a jar from tomcat service

Comment: Not sure. Tomcat does have a web  manager interface. Haven't used it, though. It might also provide that application logging for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend running it as a windows service

```
nssm install <servicename> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\java.exe" "-jar <path-to-jar-file>"
```

Comment: Is nssm a open source ? can I create a service without using any third party plugins like nssm.

Comment: Here is a link to it https://nssm.cc/  Don't forget to check the checkbox if my answer helped out. :)  There are other ways to create services too.  Just google around for command lines to create windows services and you'll find something.

Comment: I am facing this issue nssm start gives Unexpected status SERVICE_PAUSED in response to START control for java application

Answer (score 1):

This is what the official spring-boot docs say to do for Windows:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-windows.html

> Spring Boot application can be started as Windows service using winsw (https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw).
>
> A sample maintained separately to the core of Spring Boot describes step-by-step how you can create a Windows service for your Spring Boot application (https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/spring-boot-daemon).